# Crear modificaciones sobre una tabla y generar un error

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger, function

Soy nuevo con SQL y estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio con PosgreSQL que imagino que es bastante simple.

Tengo una tabla `tb_customer` con el atributo `last_update_date` (de tipo date).
Quiero hacer una modificación para que:

1. al actualizar la tabla, el atributo indique siempre la fecha actual
2. genere un error si el usuario intenta introducir el valor.

Para el caso 1), hago lo siguiente:

```
alter table erp.tb_customer
  alter column last_update set default current_date;
```

Para el caso 2), generar el error, no estoy seguro de que deba hacer lo siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_date() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.last_update IS NOT NULL; 
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER tg_update_date
  BEFORE UPDATE ON erp.tb_customer
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_update_date();
```

Es correcto cómo se crea la función `fn_update_date()`  y el trigger?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución del **punto 1** lo que hace es especificar que, por defecto (cuando la columna `last_update` no tiene valor) le coloque la fecha actual, pero al modificar un registro no va a actualizar la columna `last_update` con la fecha actual.

Tendrías que modificar la función del **punto 2**, para que:

- Al intentar modificar la columna `last_update` arroje una excepción y falle la operación.
- Actualicé la columna `last_update` con la fecha actual.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_date() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN

  -- Si el usuario está intentado modificar la columna last_update la función falla
  IF (NEW.last_update IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.last_update) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'El usuario está intentando modificar la columna last_update %.', NEW.last_update;
  END IF;

  -- Se actualiza la columna last_update con la fecha actual
  NEW.last_update = current_date;
  
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Ten en cuenta que al insertar un nuevo registro no está validando que el usuario no ingresé una fecha para la columna `last_update`, solo si no ingresa la fecha el usuario (es nula) se utilizará el valor por defecto especificado en el **punto 1**.